# Suffices to compute Cech cohomology on an arbitrarily fine cover?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-cohomology

For a topological space $X$ and a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, define the Cech cohomology groups in the usual way $$\check{H}^{q}(X, \mathscr{F}) = \varinjlim H^q(\mathfrak{U}, \mathscr{F})$$ where the limit is taken over classes of open covers $\mathfrak{U}$, ordered by refinement. To be clear, for open covers $\mathfrak{U} = \{U_i\}_{i \in I }$ and $\mathfrak{V} = \{V_j\}_{j \in J}$ we say $\mathfrak{U} \prec \mathfrak{V}$ if there is a function $\tau \colon I \to J$ such that for each $i \in I$ we have $U_i \subseteq V_{\tau(j)}$.

I would like to do some computations of cohomology, and the paper I am working out of does so by computing cohomology on open covers that we will call 'nice' and asserting that 'nice open covers are arbitrarily fine'. I need to make sure I understand the logic, and part of that is making sure I understand what arbitrarily fine means.

---

Here is what I *think* arbitrarily fine should mean: considering we have defined cohomology as a direct limit, I would say that the 'nice' open covers are 'arbitrarily fine' if given any open cover $\mathfrak{V}$, there is a 'nice' open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ such that $\mathfrak{U} \prec \mathfrak{V}$. Then if you showed that $H^{q}(\mathfrak{U}, \mathscr{F}) = 0$ for every 'nice' open cover, it would follow that the direct limit will also be trivial because this would mean everything must become 0 eventually.

---

This is in the paper:

1. The collection of all 'nice' subsets of $X$ form an open base of the topology of $X$.
2. The coverings of $X$ consisting of 'nice' subsets are arbitrarily fine.
   *proof*: Note that if $\mathfrak{U} = \{ U_i \}_{i \in I}$  is such a cover, the $U_{i_0} \cap \dots \cap U_{i_p}$ are also 'nice'.

He then defines a special type of 'nice' open cover, computes the cohomology to be trivial, then notes the the 'nice' open cover was arbitrarily fine by the above. Can someone help me solidify what is going on here?

Comment: arbitarily fine: a cofinal subset of the poset we take the inverse limit over. And it's a standard fact that the inverse limit of a cofinal subsystem is the same as that of the whole system. So yes, I agree with your interpretation.

Comment: Ok I will look into that, I guess I just didn't see why his facts (1. and 2.) above were needed to justify this

Comment: Fact 1 and 2 justify the cofinalness and the fact that the basic covers form a directed subsystem (which is what 2 says), so we *can* take a limit over just these.

Comment: Oh I see, hes not just using those facts to guarantee these covers are 'suitably fine', but we also need to make sure that the collection of them satisfies the set up in order to take a direct limit

Comment: That's what I think yes.

Comment: I didn't realize the way this worked was by finding a suitable smaller system to take a limit over. I thought we were just going to find a bunch of components of the big system and claim that they were all 0

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can formalize all of this now considering your advice

Comment: So I think Serres approach is better and more general but I think in the specific cases I’m working on, since I want cohomology to be 0, I can get by with less. That is, I don’t actually need my cofinal subset to be directed nor do I need to compute the limit over the cofinal subsystem. Since I have established cohomology is zero on a nice open cover, if I just show that the nice covers are cofinal, then everything in the system must map to zero eventually so my limit is zero too yes

Answer (score 2):

In your question you have correctly explained the meaning of "arbitrarily fine".

The crucial point is this. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be any base for the topology of $X$. A *$\mathcal{B}$-cover of $X$* is one whose members belong to $\mathcal{B}$. Then for any open cover $\mathfrak{V}$ of $X$ there exists a  $\mathcal{B}$-cover $\mathfrak{U}$ of $X$ such that $\mathfrak{U} \prec \mathfrak{V}$.

Take $I = X$. For any $x \in I$ choose $\tau(x) \in J$ such that $x \in V_{\tau(x)}$. Then choose $B(x) \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B(x) \subset V_{\tau(x)}$. Now $\mathfrak{U} = \{ B(x) \}_{x \in I}$ is finer than $\mathfrak{V}$.